# Como inserir valor de input number dentro de um select?

Tags: javascript, html, front-end

Boa noite, pessoal.

Gostaria de saber como adicionar um valor de um input number dentro de um select em JavaScript. Eu consigo imprimir tranquilamente fora do select mas dentro dele nada aparece, acho que não estou sabendo usar a função "appendChild" corretamente.

```
function adicionar(){
    let numeroInserido = document.getElementById('txtnum')
    
          
    if(numeroInserido < 0 || numeroInserido > 100){
    console.log('Número inválido')
    }
    else{
        console.log(numeroInserido.value)
        let boxNumeros = document.getElementById("selectreg")
        var numero = document.createElement("div")
        numero.innerHTML = numeroInserido.value
        boxNumeros.appendChild(numero)
        
        
    }
   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

O elemento `select` tem um descendente `option`.

Logo:

```
var option = document.createElement("option");
option.text = "Text";
option.value = numeroInserido;
var boxNumeros = document.getElementById("selectreg");
boxNumeros.appendChild(option);
```